# laravel migration commands gets stuck on command line

Tags: database, migration, laravel-5.4

Hello I have a question about laravel. I want to create an user with the migration commands, but when I do this the command line gets stuck. I looked in the .env file but all the database connections are properly set. I tried almost everything but nothing works. does somebody have some tips, or the answer?

Comment: Please be more specific. Here are some guidelines on how to ask a good question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Check your database connection setting, it is because it get stuck when connecting to database.

It could be invalid port number, database name, username or password.